# Need help translating technical video game terminology

Tags: translation, english-to-german, technical-terminology

I need to translate a video game, including the debug menu into German.

Ironically I AM German, but have accumulated all my tech and gaming vocabulary in England and now everything sounds ridiculous in German and I can’t find any professional resources.

Specifically, can somebody help me out with

- Waiting for handshake

  ("handshake" as in the very first exchange of messages when two
  devices or applications establish communication)
- Mesh Quality

  (The level of detail in rendering meshes, for example "low", "medium", "high", etc)
- Occlusion

  (lighting being affected by neighbouring objects)
- Clipping

  (objects being able to pass through another)
- Blending

  (texture details, sounds or colours being interpolated between locations, and seemingly "blending" into another)
- Cycle item

  (cycling through items: item 1 -> item 2 -> item 3 -> item 1 -> item 2, etc)

[edit] added context as requested

[edit] I've found workarounds or compromises for all but the last point. There must be a German word for "cycling through a list of items", right? Anybody?

Comment: Vielleicht waere es angebracht alle Fachbegriffe bis auf den ersten zu belassen, da kaum jemand eine Deutsche Entsprechung kennt und auch kaum Missverstaendnisse entstehen duerften. Okklusion ist auch ein Deutsches (Fach-) Wort. Ich kenne es jedoch nur aus der Medizin.

Comment: Könntest du zu den einzelnen Termini den jeweiligen Kontext angeben? Ich kann mir nämlich nicht vorstellen, in welcher Situation ich als Anwender mit der Meldung »Mesh Quality« konfrontiert sein könnte. Ohne dieses Wissen tue ich mir aber schwer, diese Meldung auf Deutsch zu formulieren. (Das gilt für alle sechs Ausdrücke!)

Comment: ludi: vielen Dank (+1), das werde ich wohl machen. 

Hubert Schölnast: Ich hab ein paar Erklärungen dazu geschrieben, aber Kontext ist "Technische Begriffe im Debug Menü eines Computerspiels". Da sollte eigentlich alles mehr oder weniger eindeutig sein (außer "clipping" vielleicht).

Comment: Ich kann @Ludi nur beipflichten. "_Debug_-Menü" hört sich nach einer Zielgruppe an, der im Zweifel mit vertrauten englischen Begriffen mehr geholfen ist als mit so noch nie gelesenen Übersetzungen.

Comment: @Matthias: I'm a little too far on the autistic spectrum to be 100% comfortable with leaving stuff half-translated, but realistically speaking you're totally right. Thanks for the confirmation guys!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is, being multiple, way to broad.

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for handshake => Auf Antwort (des Servers) warten
Occlusion => Verdeckung (klingt vielleicht ungewohnt, da aber Occlusion genau das ist, kann man es meiner Meinung nach verwenden)
Clipping würde ich als Fachbegriff lassen, es sei denn, Du willst eine Assoziation mit Genitalverstümmelung herstellen, und mit den restlichen Begriffen kann ich nichts anfangen.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've seen (as a native speaker) in many other games.

Mesh quality - Detailstufe or Objektdetails. Not an exact translation but common in video games/CG). There is also no suitable translation for mesh in this case.

(Ambient) occlusion - (Umgebungs)verdeckung

Cycle item - Iterieren/Iteration. Maybe you can offer more information of the context.

Comment: All, good answers, but I'm accepting this for the Objektdetails. Perfect compromise, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the final point I propose one of:

- Schleife
- zyklische Liste
- zirkuläre Liste

The process of cycling itself is more complicated. The nearest matches seem to be:

- durchwechseln
- durchklicken

(depending on the view point, menu or user respectively).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm after the verb "to cycle".